# extract while get the '-'

Tags: php, string

I'm having problem splitting values in php. e.g 12-23
I want to retrieve the 12 and 23 in 2 different variables. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) and [`list`](http://php.net/list):

```
list($var1, $var2) = explode('-', $str, 2);
```

Or [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
sscanf($str, '%d-%d', $var1, $var2);
```

Comment: @vimal: The third parameter is to limit the number of parts to two. So when you have more than two `-` you will always get up to two parts and the last will contain the remaining string.

Comment: ahh ok... so if i've a value of 3 digits, will get only 2 then.

Comment: @vimal: Yes. `explode('-', '12-34-56', 2)` will return `array('12', '34-56')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `explode();` function for that, http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php .

Example #1 has exactly what you've asked for!

Answer (score 0):

The [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function will do this for you.

eg. `$numbers = explode('-','12-23');`